# Nexus7 detected as mobile phone

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, extjs, nexus-7

Using the Ext JS Framework the following device is detected as a mobile phone and not as a tablet. This might be a bug in the Ext framework. Are there any known workarounds or fixes?

```
console.debug("phone: ");
console.debug((Ext.is.Phone));    //true

console.debug("tablet: ");
console.debug((Ext.is.Tablet));    //false
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.is-property-Tablet) and [source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Support.html#Ext-is) `Ext.is.Tablet` seems to be an alias of `Ext.is.iPad`.

You can probably solve this by extending `Ext.is.platforms` with a suitable regex for the Nexus7 and re-initializing the object:

```
Ext.is.platforms.push({
    property: 'userAgent'
    regex: /Nexus 7/i,
    identity: 'Nexus7'
});
Ext.is.init();

console.log(Ext.is.Nexus7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [WURFL.js](http://wurfl.io) 
Then look in 
`WURFL.form_factor`